# How to get all elements of a Haskell UArray

Tags: arrays, haskell, functional-programming, io, monads

I am practising my Haskell skills by attempting to build a command line version of Tetris. For the game board I am using UArray as I can freeze and thaw it, and that allows me to see if the current Tetris piece has collided with currently placed pieces without searching through the whole board (which is what I would need to do if I used lists). I have run into the issue that I am not sure how to convert this array to `Text` or `String` to output it to the console.

For now I am working with just one row of the board, which I initialise with the following function:

```
gameBoardWidth = 10 :: Int

initBoard :: UArray Int Char
initBoard = runSTUArray $ do
  let lastCol = gameBoardWidth - 1
  row <- newArray (0,lastCol) ' '
  return row
```

Now I am not sure how to get the `Char` out of the array for printing. [From the standard Array interface](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Array.html) `elems` looks like what I need, but that does not appear to work on `UArrays`.

```
*Main Console Lib Paths_haskell_tetris Data.Array> elems initBoard
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘Array i0 e’
                  with actual type ‘Data.Array.Base.UArray Int Char’
```

The other idea I had was to try and use the `readArray` function in a `do` block, but I am not sure how to concatenate the result of each string in a functional language

Just in case my issue is to do with the packages I have imported, these are my imports:

```
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
```

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for the reply. So is the issue that I am taking the array out of its monadic context by using `runSTUArray`,  and I need to put it back in its context in order to actually read and write to it? What is the difference between `IOUArray` and `STUArray`, they look like the same interface, is it just that they have different internal implementations?

Comment: In your test, you are calling `Data.Array.elems`, but it looks like you need to call `Data.Array.IArray.elems` instead. Perhaps an `import qualified ... as ...` can help you to point to the "right" function. By the way, constantly freezing/thawing your arrays has a cost, since you need to make a copy. A mutable array as Willem suggests should be more performant, since it's the rough equivalent to the arrays we get in imperative languages.

Comment: @chi that works, if in GHCI I run `> Data.Array.IArray.elems initBoard` I get `"          "` which is what I expect. For some reason your answer doesn't show in a way that I can accept it as an answer though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test uses `Data.Array.elems` which only works on `Array`.

You need to call instead the class method `Data.Array.IArray.elems` which works on any immutable array, including `UArray`.